# Cloud service for image uploads

Tags: image, upload, cloud, disqus

Im looking for a 3d party image uploading service working like disqus.
This means, you have for each url something like a virtual directory where you can upload files to and see all files uploaded to that particular url.

I checked cloudinary and those, none of them supports this kind of directory-based working.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that Cloudinary can support this kind of virtual directory working for [image upload](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration).

All your images, derived images and required metadata are stored and managed by Cloudinary in Amazon S3 buckets owned by Cloudinary.

Cloudinary also allows using your own S3 bucket instead of Cloudinary’s buckets. This option is available for Premium users and requires permission assignment to Cloudinary's AWS user.

A solution for your case is to use Amazon's S3 tool called [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) that supports virtual folder option to maintain files. Bucket Explorer creates a file that ends with ""/"" for virtual folder and supports backward compatibility for some popular tools.